# Solving an ODE/IVP for modified logistic equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Alright, so I see a bunch of modified logistic equations here already but none seem to be pointing me any closer to an answer:

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=kP(M-P)$$

where $k$ and $m$ are positive constants. We’re told to solve it as a separable equation, which I’ve done, giving me:

$$P(t)=M\frac{e^{Mkt+MC}}{e^{Mkt+MC}-1}$$

This solution makes sense, since the fraction will asymptotically approach 1 with increasing $t$ and therefore the value of $P$ will gradually approach the carrying capacity $M$.

This is all good until we’re told to solve the following IVP for this same ODE:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{dP}{dt}= kP(M-P)\\
\ P(0) = \frac M 3
\end{cases}
$$

Using the solution for $P(t)$ I found earlier, this yields no solution. I get stuck around  $e^{MC}-1=3e^{MC}$ which makes no mathematical sense for further computation to find the value for $C$ that satisfies the IVP.

But to make matters even more confusing, I’ve worked through the verification to ensure that the $P(t)$ I found is indeed a valid general solution to the ODE. The IVP is where it all breaks down, and I can’t figure out why.

And there should be exactly one solution to the IVP per the existence-uniqueness theorem, since both $f(t,P)=\frac{dP}{dt}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial P}$ are continuous for all $(t,P)$ on $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your general solution is correct
$$\frac{M}{3}=M\frac{e^{MC}}{e^{MC}-1}$$
$$e^{MC}-1=3e^{MC}$$ is strange, actually


But on Wolfram alpha I found the IVP solution $$P(t) = \frac{Me^{k M t} }{2 + e^{k M t}}$$
which makes sense  and solves both the IVP
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dP%2Fdt%3DkP(M-P)+,P(0)%3DM%2F3

Comment: i have found this here $$P \left( t \right) ={\frac {M}{1+2\,{{\rm e}^{-kMt}}}}$$

Comment: multiplying numerator and denominator by $$e^ {kMt}$$ we get the same solution like above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so that others can avoid the torture I went through:

$$e^{MC}=-\frac 1 2$$

Per the [complex logarithm](http://www.rapidtables.com/math/algebra/logarithm/Logarithm_of_Negative_Number.htm):
$$C=\frac{i\pi-\ln{2}}{M}$$

Substituting this back into $P(t)$ as defined in the question:

$$P(t)=M\frac{e^{Mkt+i\pi-\ln{2}}}{e^{Mkt+i\pi-\ln{2}}-1}$$

From logarithm rules (simplifying $e^{\ln 2} = 2$):
$$P(t)=M\frac{\frac{e^{Mkt}e^{i\pi}}{2}}{\frac{e^{Mkt}e^{i\pi}}{2}-1}$$
$$P(t)=M\frac{e^{Mkt}e^{i\pi}}{e^{Mkt}e^{i\pi}-2}$$

Now, from [Euler’s formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$, so $e^{i\pi} =\cos\pi -i\sin\pi=-1$.

$$P(t)=-M\frac{e^{Mkt}}{-e^{Mkt}-2}$$

Simplifying,

$$P(t)=M\frac{e^{Mkt}}{e^{Mkt}+2}$$

which makes sense by allowing $P$ to approach the carrying capacity $M$ from below with increasing $t$ but never equal it.